# Display an imageView on the HomeScreen

Tags: android, image, homescreen

Currently I am in the process of learning and I stumbled upon one problem which is giving me headaches. My goal is to display an custom image on the Homescreen. Could anyone guide me into the right direction. I also would prefer that the code for the solution will not be posted since copying and pasting would not help me much learning how to code.
Thank you in advance for any hints & tips.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either you are writing your own home screen, or you are not.

If you are writing your own home screen, you would display an `ImageView` there no different than with any other activity.

If you are not writing your own home screen, the only way you can display *anything* on the home screen is by writing [an app widget](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html) (which can contain an `ImageView`) or a [live wallpaper](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2010/02/live-wallpapers.html).

Comment: I will definitely look into app widgets. Thanks!